# drop down banner ads needed

Tags: jquery

Hi I need a drop down banner ads on a project I am working on. it's like a toggle effect but with the choice to close it or automatically closes after sometime and pushes it down.
it would be similar to http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/dddropdownpanel.htm but by default should visible just don't know how to put the time duration to close it. By any chance can someone show me how to add it to the javascript
something like

```
$(function(){
   $("#banner").slideDown(function()  {
       setTimeout(function() {             
         $("#banner").slideUp(); 
       }, 30000);
   });
});
```

The javascript Im using is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#toggle-view li').click(function () {

        var text = $(this).children('p');

        if (text.is(':hidden')) {
            text.slideDown('200');
            $(this).children('span').html('-');     
        } else {
            text.slideUp('200');
            $(this).children('span').html('+');     
        }

    });

    });
```

Comment: What doesn't work in the script above? It should work fine - the banner will slide up after 30 seconds..

Comment: sorry i just edited my post with the second script I just need to insert the 1st script on the scond script but for some reason it won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code works fine

```
$(function(){
   $("#banner").slideDown(function()  {
       setTimeout(function() {             
         $("#banner").slideUp(); 
       }, 5000); //slide up after 5 seconds
   });
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/BgVtY/

Comment: Thanks need but is it possible to add this code to the second one I just posted doesnt seem to work

Comment: @cooldude, can you post both it and the html to a fiddle so i can try to fix it?

Comment: I can't seem to get it work on fiddle but it's working on my site http://j2sdesign.com/jsf/test.html other problem is when the image closed it flickers

Comment: ok got it working now sorry for that thanks for your help I just need to fix the image flickering when It close

Comment: sorry about that I was checking the image flickering didn't notice I didn't accept answer